# 'Clean Cell content' based upon cell backgroundcolor

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to "delete any text" from table cells that have a "White Backgroundcolor" in a Word document

[image]

The following code works for Excel, but NOT for WORD

```
Sub colorbasedclearcontent()
    Range("C2:M11").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
            Cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Anybody can (help me) translate this to work in a Word Document?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the object of a cell, which is within a collection of a table, which is a part of a document object. Microsoft [has documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell) that explains the various objects.

In Excel, it's different. A cell is part of a range or an overall worksheet which is part of a workbook object.

This will loop through all your document tables, rows and then cells.

```
Sub testTable()
Const colorCode = -603914241  ''depending on your version of white it could be a couple options.
'might also be -16777216  or 16777215


Dim t As Table, aRow As Row, aCell As Cell
For Each t In ThisDocument.Tables
    For Each aRow In t.Rows
        For Each aCell In aRow.Cells
            
            If aCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = colorCode Then
                aCell.Range.Text = ""
            End If
            
        Next aCell
    Next aRow
Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code didn't work a 100% in my case (tables), but got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the target table is the first table in the document

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Target As Table
    Set Target = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

    Dim c As Cell
    For Each c In Target.Range.Cells
        If c.Shading.Texture = 0 _
        And c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 0 Then 
            c.Range.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This would clear any cell in the table that doesn't have a shading color.

Answer (score 0):

'Thanks to 'pgSystemTester'

'It helped me to write a working code depending on the different colorcodes used.

```
Sub cleartext() 
Dim tbl As Table 
Dim ro As Row 
Dim c As Cell
 
  For Each ro In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows
    For Each c In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells

    If c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic Then
        c.Range.Text = ""
    ElseIf c.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603914241 Then
        c.Range.Text = ""
    End If

  Next c   
 Next ro 
End Sub
```